# Sending a signal to two programs at the same time

Tags: windows-xp, video, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to hear your ideas on solving the following problem.

Suppose I have a video player which doesn't allow for multiple subtitles showing up on the screen. I can work around this by using Penguin subtitle player, a simple program that basically allows the user to lay over the video player's window anther transparent window, which only shows subtitles from a file. Once the two programs are in sync, one is good to go.

The problem is of course when one needs to pause the video: one needs to pause the video player and the penguin player, which inevitably results in a delay and one loses the sync.

I was thinking there should be a way to pause both programs by hitting one key only. A poor man's solution is to hit space bar on one program and using the mouse to pause the other and try to do this almost at the same time.

What do you think? Is there a way to send the pause signal to both programs bu performing one action only? I am running Windows XP.

Edit: some video players, e.g., the one on the netflix website, don't allow for multiple subtitles, and that is why I am asking this question.

Comment: Any reason why you dont use VLC? You can input the subtitles directly into the video stream.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion would also be to go for VLC. Otherwise... does Penguin have a shortcut-key for stopping and resuming display? If so you could use autoit3 (or some other program) to send both your player and Penguin the corresponding shortcut-keys for stopping and resuming and a certain other shortcut-key you can choose.

Comment: I made an edit that should answer your questions on VLC. Rik: could you elaborate a bit more on this program? I'm pretty sure the spacebar pauses Penguin player.

Comment: @vap and which video player are you using? What is the pause/resume shortcut-key for that? Autoit3 can register a shortcut-key (ctrl+q for instance) and it can send keystrokes (like space etc) to other programs. That easy you could pause your player and penguin at the same time with the same keystroke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a very easy way to do what I was looking for. One can use Auto Hotkey and a script like this:

```
Space::
KeyWait, Space, D
ControlSend,, {Space}, Netflix - Mozilla Firefox
ControlSend,, {Space}, Penguin Subtitle Player - Penguin Subtitle Player
Return
```

This will send the key "Space" to both applications causing them to stop (this is because each of those application has a keyboard shortcut to pause the video, and that key is "Space"). Of course one can modify this by changing the key and the title of the windows to be controlled.